# retrieve Telerik DatePicker value to a field named differently than the control id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

This works fine:

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("FieldName").Value(Model.FieldName))
```

as does this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(x => x.FieldName)
```

But I'd like to have a name/id for the control that is different from my data model field name.  If I do this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("DifferentName").Value(Model.FieldName))
```

then the control is initialized properly from `Model.FieldName`, but the storage is not bound to it.  How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Telerik's `InputHtmlAttributes` method to assign a unique ID to the input control:

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(x => Model.DataField)
    .InputHtmlAttributes(new {id="UniqueID"}))
```

Note that this is different than `HtmlAttributes` which affects a wrapper div and not the input control.